# Virtuoso fails to run after any update to virtuoso.ini

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, virtuoso

I've installed [Virtuoso OpenSource](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/) 7.2.+ on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. When I change `virtuoso.ini` (any change such as adding a new directory to the `DirsAllowed`), the server fails to work; when I set the configurations back to its defaults, then it's working. Any idea here?

Comment: The `virtuoso.log` file, typically found alongside `virtuoso.ini` and `virtuoso.db`, is likely to reveal something. Starting the instance with `+foreground` argument may show you more, as it happens. Note: Virtuoso-specific questions are often answered more quickly via [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), OpenLink's [public support forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), or [confidential support cases](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp). (ObDisclaimer: I work for OpenLink Software.)

Comment: @TallTed, thanks, I checked the log it says at the last line **Server exiting**! And now, when I go with its default configuration, it is not working anymore. I think it is probably because **there exists a transaction log from an earlier version** right?

Comment: The last line of the log is not necessarily the one that matters. Guessing at the issue is not likely to bring a quick resolution. Try pasting the entire log from the last launch attempt through to its termination into your question; that gives us something to work from. Or provide the same through one of the other channels I mentioned...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is solved!
The problem, as I said, was because of existing a transaction log from an earlier version. It seems this is an old bug in Virtuoso according to [Bug286953](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=286953).

Anyway, I removed `virtuoso.trx` file and restarted my machine, it's now working.

Comment: So the problem was not changes in the INI file, but an upgrade of the binary executable. Next time, please try following the [Virtuoso Upgrade instructions](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/UpgradingToVOS610#Introduction), which include running a `CHECKPOINT`, which leaves an empty transaction log (or no such file) and ensures that all prior data changes persist through the upgrade. (Note that the bug you linked was against KDE and Nepomuk, not Virtuoso.)

Comment: @TallTed, thanks for your comments, yes actually `INI` file made me problems after any update, otherwise the server was working fine when I resat to its default configurations, but after that it didn't work even when resetting to its defaults so it ended up with deleting `.rtx` file! For the bug, yes actually it's related to KDE and Nepomuk but it works for Virtuoso as well. And thanks for the support links they're just great!

Comment: OK. I'm glad things are working now. Now please mark your answer as accepted, so this question shows up as answered...